# move() function not working in laravel 5.2 while editing/updating pictures

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a founder page where the user can upload name, information and image of the founder.
In my view when I edit pictures and upload a new one, the name of the pictures gets stored in the database but the image is not being uploaded. There must be some problem in my controller but i can't seem to find out what. Any help would be appreciated.

Below are my model, controller and view.

[Founder Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlZfn.png)

```
class Founder extends Model
{
     protected $fillable = ['name','information', 'image'];

     public function getImageAttribute()
     {
         if (! $this->attributes['image']) {
           return 'noimage.jpg';
     }

     return $this->attributes['image'];
}
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($date)
{
    return Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date)->format('Y-m-d');
}

public function getUpdatedAtAttribute($date)
{
    return Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date)->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

[Founder Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTxgx.png)

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

    $founder = Founder::find($id);
    $input  = $request->all();

    if($file=$request->file('image'))
    {
        $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move('/images/', $name);
        $input['image']= $name;
    }
    $founder->update($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('founder.view');

}
```

Founder View Edit Form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="/founders/{{$founder->id}}" method="POST">

           {{csrf_field()}}

              <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-12">Name</label>
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                     <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="{{$founder->name}}"> 
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-12">Information</label>
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                      <textarea class="form-control" name="information" rows="3" value="{{$founder->information}}">{{$founder->information}}</textarea>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-12">Change Image</label>
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                       <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control" value="{{$founder->image}}"> 
                  </div>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light m-r-10">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Please include your actual code not just screenshots of it. Nobody is willing to type over your code.

Comment: just edited the question with the code. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use rename:

```
rename ('current/path/to/foo', 'new/path/to/foo');
```

Documentation: http://php.net/rename

UPDATE:
Or use variable $destinationPath:

```
$file->move($destinationPath, $chooseYourFileName);
```

Comment: neither of the options worked. Image name is being updated but the file still isn't uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

> Use This Method This Will Work 100%

```
if($request->hasFile('filename')){

     $file = $request->filename;

    $file_new_name =  $file->move("upload/posts/", $file->getClientOriginalName());



     $post->filename = $file_new_names;

   }
```

> Remember filename is your < img name="filename" >